# “Hasidic Zmanim “

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, tefilla

Something that has always piqued my interest is how some hasidic groups sometimes daven way later than the zman, is there any halachic validity to doing this?- I was under the assumption that if you are minute past the zman , you missed the boat.

Comment: Originally the 'chasidic'-reformers (ie. those who changed from then-traditional jewish practice and became what's now just called "chasidim") were put in cherem for blatant violations of Jewish law like this, but then everyone else got too busy fighting what became known as the "Reform" movement to bother.

Comment: Actually, the concept of davening beyond what most consider beyond the Zman is learned from a teaching of the Ari z”l with Chaim Vital while they were standing at the Kinneret.

Comment: @DoubleAA source for such a statement?

Comment: @YaacovDeane what's the teaching ?

Comment: @TwoOs it's basic Jewish History that you can easily google and read about in dozens of places. Here's the first link I checked on Google https://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/hasidim-and-mitnagdim

Comment: @TwoOs A similar story bringing the concept: https://www.inner.org/spiritual-masters/rebbe-menachem-mendel-of-vitebsk-prayers-hovering-over-the-kinneret